# Call Asp.net Method (which contains controls) with Jquery Post

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a asp.net method which clears an asp:DropdownList control.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public void clear()
{
    cloneSrcEnvList.Items.Clear();
}
```

My goal is to call this function with a JQuery/Ajax request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function BtnClick(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Tools.aspx/clear",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });

    }
    </script>
```

But i'm getting this error due to Static "**500 (Internal Server Error)"**.  If I declare the clear method as Static the DropDownlist cause an error

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Do you have any idea or tips?

Comment: The static web method doesn't know about the server controls on the page, so it's not possible to clear the asp:DropDownList using the static web method.

Comment: Is It possible to call a non static method with jquery ?

Comment: No it's not possible unfortunately. You'll have to call non static method using button click event handler like this: `<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button_Click"></asp:Button>`. `Button_Click` is the method in code behind.

Comment: It will made a postback on the page and i'm looking a way to call a method ( with button)  without postback.

Answer (score 0):

A control in an ASP.NET web page cannot be changed and persisted this way.  The context within the static web method knows nothing about the execution of the page.  You could wrap the page in an `<asp:UpdatePanel>` control and trigger a postback to clear it.  The page would think it's a normal postback, but the user only sees an AJAX request/response...

Unfortunately this is one of the challenges with ASP.NET web forms and AJAX.

Comment: The thing is i'm looking a way to Call a method which made change on asp:Control without a postback.

Comment: All a DropDownList control is a `<select>` element and in theory you can use JavaScript to clear the list.  However, to my knowledge ASP.NET validates the list of items is the same as the previous postback and this causes an error, which is annoying.  There may be workarounds to that, which googling may help.  I don't remember if there is.  The UpdatePanel is usually the simplest option because of the complexities of web forms.  AJAX web service is not an option here though.

Answer (score 0):

To call the method using AJAX we need to declare a function with the static keyword. 
whenever you declare any method with static keyword, it doesn't have a definition of a control so you can not find any server control reference in this method.

please see below link

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-server-side-function-from-JavaScript-in-ASP.Net.aspx